# Hide Menu Items from guess user with ACF

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I want to know is there any way to hide some menu item from guess user, with ACF plugin.
I know there is a lot of plugins with the build for this reason.
but I want to just use ACF. Is it possible?

Comment: ACF is for adding custom fields to things, why would it be able to hide menu items?

Comment: I saw it is possible to add some fields to a menu item by ACF. can I add a drop menu field like "for log in" and "for log out"?and make a condition for these fields.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/)?

Comment: yes. I know how to add. but I down know how to make conditions and connect it to the menu item to hide it visible them.